# How to prevent memory leaks in WPF caused by Brush

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, memory-leaks, brush

A SolidColorBrush used as a DynamicResource causing a major memory leak as it retains 2 references to a ResourceRefenceExpression (by EventHandler and ModifiedValue).

It's written that this bug has been solved on .NET 4.0 but unfortunately it's still there... (on .NET 4.5).

I've found 2 (inefficient) workarounds:

- Freeze static brushes.
- setting dynamic brushes to be non shared.

Please assist me on figuring out the following issues:

1. How does this leak occur on .NET 4.5 ?
2. Setting 1000+ brushes to be non shared can be very expensive, is there more efficient way to overcome this leak?

Comment: Your post is very vague. Do you have any reference to this bug, a link into the MSDN or Microsoft KB entry or a code snippet that demonstrates the bug?

Comment: Seen this by any chance? http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2651992. It says it does not occur in .Net 4 so I assume it should be same in 4.5 too.

Comment: why is freezing the brushes inefficient for you?

Comment: freezing is efficient, but it's effective only on static resources.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the link, but the brushes are still leaky.

Comment: without example code you aren't likely to get much help...